# Export a function which has an imported axios response data

Tags: javascript, axios

Currently I have two files, one is being used to fetch and get the data response. The other js file is to import these results in a function. I would like to export this last function so I could use it in other files.

#### api.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const url = 'data/data.json';
const cars = 'data/cars.json';

export const fetchData = () => { 
  return axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
}

export const fetchCars = () => { 
  return axios.get(cars)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
}
```

#### import.js

See: `export const details`

```js
import { fetchData, fetchCars } from './api';
let fetchingData = fetchData();
let fetchingCars = fetchCars();

// I want to export the below functionality:

fetchingData.then((result) => {
  // I will be doing stuff here
  console.log(result);
})

export const details = () => {
  fetchingCars.then((result) => {
    // I will be doing stuff here
    console.log(result);
  })
}

// And be able to console.log the results out of that exported function. Since I will need to update DOM values based on the API results.
console.log(details);
```

#### importCars.js

```js
import { details } from './import'

function example() {
  // do something
  details();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the fetchData in api.js as below,

```
export const fetchData = () => { 
  return axios.get(url)
}
```

And in import.js use `result.data` instead of `result` while logging like below,

```
fetchingData.then((result) => {
  // I will be doing stuff here
  console.log(result.data);
})
```